# Why can't I loop through my json object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I am using jquery to loop through json object... But some how it doesn't seem to work...

Here is my code,

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
      //      data: "{}",
      data: "{'currentPage':1,'pagesize':5}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(jsonObj) {
          alert(jsonObj);
          for (var i = jsonObj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var employee = jsonObj[i];
            alert(employee.Emp_Name);
```

When alerted my `jsonObj` i got `[object Object]` but when i alerted `jsonObj.length` it showed `undefined` any suggestion....

**EDIT:**

using the answer below i cant iterate through divs,

```
$.each(jsonObj, function(i, employee) {
   $('<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee[i].Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].Address + '</span></div>').insertAfter('#ResultsDiv');
 });
```

My json object will be this,

```
{
  "Table": [{
    "Row": "1",
    "Emp_Id": "3",
    "Emp_Name": "Jerome",
    "Address": "Madurai",
    "Desig_Name": "Supervisior",
    "SalaryBasis": "Monthly",
    "FixedSalary": "25000.00"
  }, {
    "Row": "2",
    "Emp_Id": "4",
    "Emp_Name": "Mohan",
    "Address": "Madurai",
    "Desig_Name": "Acc ",
    "SalaryBasis": "Monthly",
    "FixedSalary": "200.00"
  }, {
    "Row": "3",
    "Emp_Id": "5",
    "Emp_Name": "Murugan",
    "Address": "Madurai",
    "Desig_Name": "Mason",
    "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
    "FixedSalary": "150.00"
  }, {
    "Row": "4",
    "Emp_Id": "6",
    "Emp_Name": "Ram",
    "Address": "Madurai",
    "Desig_Name": "Mason",
    "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
    "FixedSalary": "120.00"
  }, {
    "Row": "5",
    "Emp_Id": "7",
    "Emp_Name": "Raja",
    "Address": "Madurai",
    "Desig_Name": "Mason",
    "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
    "FixedSalary": "135.00"
  }]
}
```

My inspected through firebug in the `json` tab i got this

`{"Table" : [{"Row" : "1...edSalary" : "135.00"}]}`...

`Response` i got was

```
{"d":"{\"Table\" : [{\"Row\" : \"1\",\"Emp_Id\" : \"3\",\"Emp_Name\" : \"Jerome\",\"Address\" : \"Madurai\",\"Desig_Name\" : \"Supervisior\",\"SalaryBasis\" : \"Monthly\",\"FixedSalary\" : \"25000.00\"},{\"Row\" : \"2\",\"Emp_Id\" : \"4\",\"Emp_Name\" : \"Mohan\",\"Address\" : \"Madurai\",\"Desig_Name\" : \"Acc \",\"SalaryBasis\" : \"Monthly\",\"FixedSalary\" : \"200.00\"},{\"Row\" : \"3\",\"Emp_Id\" : \"5\",\"Emp_Name\" : \"Murugan\",\"Address\" : \"Madurai\",\"Desig_Name\" : \"Mason\",\"SalaryBasis\" : \"Weekly\",\"FixedSalary\" : \"150.00\"},{\"Row\" : \"4\",\"Emp_Id\" : \"6\",\"Emp_Name\" : \"Ram\",\"Address\" : \"Madurai\",\"Desig_Name\" : \"Mason\",\"SalaryBasis\" : \"Weekly\",\"FixedSalary\" : \"120.00\"},{\"Row\" : \"5\",\"Emp_Id\" : \"7\",\"Emp_Name\" : \"Raja\",\"Address\" : \"Madurai\",\"Desig_Name\" : \"Mason\",\"SalaryBasis\" : \"Weekly\",\"FixedSalary\" : \"135.00\"}]}"}
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: This might be easier if you would also show us an example jsonObj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's `each` method. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
success: function(jsonObj) {

         $.each(jsonObj, function(i, employee) {

            alert(employee.Emp_Name);

         }
}
```

Also, AFAIK, `alert()` on its own won't show a JSON structure.

And because it is an object (not an array), I don't think it'll have a length property.

Also, is there any reason you would prefer counting down in that for loop to counting up? It is an optimisation trick?

### Update

After seeing some example JSON, i.e.

```
{
   Table: [
      {
         Row: '1',
         Emp_Id: '3',
         Emp_Name: 'Jerome',
         Address: 'Madurai',
         Desig_Name: 'Supervisior',
         SalaryBasis: 'Monthly',
         FixedSalary: '25000.00'
      },
      {
         Row: '2',
         Emp_Id: '4',
         Emp_Name: 'Mohan',
         Address: 'Madurai',
         Desig_Name: 'Acc ',
         SalaryBasis: 'Monthly',
         FixedSalary: '200.00'
      },
      {
         Row: '3',
         Emp_Id: '5',
         Emp_Name: 'Murugan',
         Address: 'Madurai',
         Desig_Name: 'Mason',
         SalaryBasis: 'Weekly',
         FixedSalary: '150.00'
      },
      {
         Row: '4',
         Emp_Id: '6',
         Emp_Name: 'Ram',
         Address: 'Madurai',
         Desig_Name: 'Mason',
         SalaryBasis: 'Weekly',
         FixedSalary: '120.00'
      },
      {
         Row: '5',
         Emp_Id: '7',
         Emp_Name: 'Raja',
         Address: 'Madurai',
         Desig_Name: 'Mason',
         SalaryBasis: 'Weekly',
         FixedSalary: '135.00'
      }
   ]
}
```

it would seem you would want to access an employee name like so

```
 $.each(jsonObj.table, function(i, employee) {

                alert(employee.Emp_Name);

             }
```

Comment: @alex `employee.Emp_Name` is `undefined`

Comment: @alex counting down is iterating my json through divs and i am `insertafter` a div.. This would arrange the div as by my datatable

Comment: @Pandiya You're not using the correct code. You're trying to access an element with `[i]`, but jQuery makes the iteration available through the `employee` object.

Comment: @alex i have used your code still i get the error `alert(employee.Emp_Name)` is `undefined`

Comment: @alex my server side json string was the one i posted... But still same undefined error...

Comment: @alex look at my edit and see the bottom of my question about the `response` i received...

Comment: Your JSON is a bit weird in that new update. It looks like you'll need to evaluate (`eval()`) `jsonObj.d`

Comment: @alex i got it working now... `var jsob = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonObj.d);`

Comment: @alex: Not sure about this case, but looping backwards is often an optimization trick, notice that you only need to call the `.length` property once. However, most browsers nowadays are optimized so that calling `.length` multiple times (without modifying the array) does not cause a measurable difference.

Answer (score 1):

The **length** property is only available to **Array** objects.

**Json** objects, and by extension objects that are accessed as key value pairs have to be iterated using a for loop like this:

```
for(aProperty in jsonObj)
{
  var employee = jsonObj[aProperty];
  alert(aProperty + " = " + employee);
}
```

or using the **jQuery.each** alternative:

```
jQuery.each(jsonObj, function(key,value))
{
   alert(key + " = " + value);
}
```

**window.alert** may not offer the best tools to for debugging and object display. 
You should try using  [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/).

I'm guessing you want to  insert all that html after $('#ResultsDiv');

Try adjusting your code like so:

```
$.each(jsonObj.Table, function(i, employee) {
 $('<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee[i].Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee[i].Address + '</span></div>').insertAfter('#ResultsDiv');
 });
```

It seems like the employee records are contained in one property **Table** which is what you should be iterating.

Also make sure that $('#ResultsDiv') exists.

Here's a suggestion for your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
            data: "{'currentPage':1,'pagesize':5}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(jsonObj) {
            var Employees = jsonObj.Table || jsonObj.d.Table;
            for(key in Employees) console.log(Employees);
            }
        })
```

Comment: @Olaseni `jquery.each` does the trick.. But how to iterate my div which is in my question inside this loop...

Comment: Note that when using `for in` in JavaScript, in certain cases you'll iterate through more than you like (because of prototypal inheritance). This is where `hasOwnProperty()` can help.

Comment: @Olaseni see my edit and especially my bottom of the screen `response` i received by inspecting through firebug...

Comment: @Pandiya Are you using json specific methods i.e. $.getJSON?

Or are you using $.get, or $.post?

Comment: @Pandiya You don't need to eval, jQuery already done that by specifying - dataType: json in the ajax call. See my edits

Try these: 

var Employees = jsonObj.Table || jsonObj.d.Table;

See my full code excerpt above

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't have a length. You can iterate through object's properties like this:

```
success: function(jsonObj) {
         alert(jsonObj);
         for (i in jsonObj) {
             var employee = jsonObj[i];
             alert(employee.Emp_Name);
```

Comment: @kkyy `employee.Emp_Name` is `undefined`